# Построение аудио спектра в реальном времени

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, fft

Всем привет. Мне нужен анализатор спектра в реальном времени как в звуковых плеерах. На языке python. Код для чтение wav файла и fft готов, но не понимаю как строить "столбики звука". Пробовал через matplotlib. Нечего не вышло. Заранее спасибо.

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import time

# Указываем путь до аудио файла
myAudio = "2.wav"

# Чтение файла и получение частоты дискретизации и звукового объект
samplingFreq, mySound = wavfile.read(myAudio)

# Проверяем является ли wave-файл 16-битным или 32-битным. (24 бит не поддерживается)
mySoundDataType = mySound.dtype

# Мы можем преобразовать наш звуковой массив в значения с плавающей запятой в диапазоне от -1 до 1 следующим образом

mySound = mySound / (2. ** 15)

# Проверим точки отсчета и звуковой канал для двух каналов или для моноканала

mySoundShape = mySound.shape
samplePoints = float(mySound.shape[0])

# Если два канала, то выберем только один кана
mySoundOneChannel = mySound[0:]

# График частотного содержания
# Мы можем получить частоту из амплитуды и времени с помощью БПФ, быстрого алгоритма преобразования Фурье
# Получим длину моего массива звуковых объектов
mySoundLength = len(mySound)

# Возьмем преобразование Фурье для данной точки отсчета
fftArray = fft(mySoundOneChannel)

numUniquePoints = int(numpy.ceil((mySoundLength + 1) / 2.0))
fftArray = fftArray[0:numUniquePoints]

# БПФ содержит как величину, так и фазу и задается комплексными числами в формате действительных + мнимых частей (a + ib).
# Принимая абсолютное значение, мы получаем только действительную часть.

fftArray = abs(fftArray)

# Масштабируйте массив fft по длине точек выборки, чтобы величина не зависела отдлина сигнала или его частота дискретизации

fftArray = fftArray / float(mySoundLength)

# БПФ имеет как положительную, так и отрицательную информацию. Площадь возводим в квадрат, чтобы получить только положительные значения
fftArray = fftArray ** 2

if mySoundLength % 2 > 0:  # у нас есть нечетное число точек в FFT
    fftArray[1:len(fftArray)] = fftArray[1:len(fftArray)] * 2

else:  # У нас есть чётное количество точек в БПФ
    fftArray[1:len(fftArray) - 1] = fftArray[1:len(fftArray) - 1] * 2

freqArray = numpy.arange(0, numUniquePoints, 1.0) * (samplingFreq / mySoundLength)

plt...........
plt.xlabel('Частота (Khz)')
plt.ylabel('Мощность (dB)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Самая сложная часть задачи, ИМХО, - понять, что именно отрисовывают полосовые анализаторы. Как они агрегируют амплитуды отдельных частот в полосу?

Если с этим получится справиться, то дальше всё просто. Разложить очередную секунду сигнала по частотам, агрегировать, отрисовать столбики.

Я не нашел, как агрегируют частоты в полоски анализаторы, поэтому своим произволом постановил считать, что там рисуют удельную энергию, приходящуюся на диапазон. То есть сумма квадратов амплитуд делённая на ширину диапазона.

```
def bandpower(samples, sampling_rate, freq_ranges):
    """Функция возвращаем массив, каждый элемент которого есть удельная энергия, приходящаяся на заданный интервал частот.
    samples - массив амплитуд сигнала (например, из wav файла).
    sampling_rate - частота дискретизации.
    freq_ranges - списко частот, ограничивающих интервалы.
    """
    result = []
    # Преобразование Фурье, оптимизированная функция для вещественных значений
    fft_data = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(samples))
    fft_data_sq = fft_data*fft_data
    # У этой функции нет отрицательных значений частот
    fft_freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(samples), d=1.0/sampling_rate)
    for f1, f2 in zip(freq_ranges[:-1], freq_ranges[1:]):
        mask = np.logical_and(f1 <= fft_freqs, fft_freqs < f2)
        # Интегрирование квадрата амплитуды по каждому из диапазонов
        # Энергия приводится к ширине диапазона
        power = np.trapz(y=fft_data_sq[mask], x=fft_freqs[mask])/(f2-f1)
        result.append(power)
    return np.array(result)
```

Я рекомендую использовать для разложения Фурье функцию `np.fft.rfft`. Эта функция оптимизирована для разложения вещественнозначных волн, и парная ей функция `np.fft.rfftfreq` не содержит отрицательных частот, поэтому не требуются трюки с отрезанием лишних значений.

Если в функции `bandpower` не делить на ширину диапазона, то получится перекос в сторону 4-й и 5-й октав. Просто потому, что они самые широкие, по ширине как все предыдущие вместе взятые.

Код для отрисовки полос средствами анимации `matplotlib` я загрузил в [блокнот Jupyter](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/python/1289610/band_demo.ipynb). Github не умеет показывать анимацию поэтому в блокноте есть код, который отрисовывает спектры для первых 10 секундных отрывков Имперского марша в статике.

Наверное, для полного соответствия обычным анализаторам нужно логарифмировать полученные значения и рисовать в децибелах, но ... Для этого нужно выбрать какой-то единичный уровень, а у меня нет никаких идей, как именно звуковики это делают.

**UPDATE**

Я вспомнил, откуда упёр идею `bandpower` - с какого-то форума по Matlab. Там как раз спрашивали, как сделать band analyzer. Сейчас ссылку найти не могу. Но мысль про среднюю энергию я почерпнул от них, совершенно точно.

Comment: частоты при разложении в ряд выбираешь с дескритизацией по количеству столбиков. квадраты складывать не надо - просто амплитуда в нужном месте.

Comment: @eri не-не-не, тогда надо перерисовывать 2 тысячи раз в секунду. 
Я вспомнил, откуда упёр идею `bandwidth` - из какого-то обсуждения на форуме Матлаба. Там как раз про полосовой анализатор спрашивали.

Comment: смотря для каких целей анализатор. для экранной дергалки я делал срез 1/15 секунды разложив в ряд фурье только по нужным частотам. При коротком срезе каждая частота дает довольно широкий спектр.

Comment: @eri да, так тоже можно. Так устроен "анализатор спектра" на Arduino. На светодиоды выводят результат FFT для 64 сэмплов. А в старом добром Winamp не так - у них уровень сигнала определяется как среднее значение амплитуды по диапазону. У меня как среднее значение квадрата амплитуды, так же как в matlab. Короче, без физической модели "анализатора" невозможно сказать, как правильно.